# Please explain AngularJs ng-click behavior in Debug

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a paginate directive I have:

```
<tr dir-paginate="item in NumDen | itemsPerPage: 10">
 <td><span ng-click="EditThis()"ng-bind=item.Id ></span></td>
 <td ng-bind=item.Name></td>
</tr>
```

In my controller I have:

```
    $scope.EditThis = function () {
    alert(this.item.Id);
}
```

When I watch it in the Chrome debugger, I see I have a 'this' object that contains all the values for a singular item as well as other attributes. This was a wonderful, unexpected surprise.

Is this standard AngularJS functionality, to get the object that was bound to the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably thinking in terms of a jQuery event handler where  `this` is the element.

`ng-click` however has no element context or model data context , it simply invokes the expression contained in it's attribute value using the context of the angular scope where it resides.

Pass `item` as argument of your function:

```
ng-click="EditThis(item)"
```

Then in controller:

```
$scope.EditThis = function (item) {
    alert(item.Id);
}
```